# ¿How can I create a dynamic FOR loop that prints a bar chart depending on a dataset grouped by factor levels?

Tags: r, for-loop, bar-chart

I have a dataframe (locs.new) of daily distances traveled by radiotagged birds. I'm trying to create a function that calls a **for** loop that creates a subset for the **i**th sparrow (identified by a character variable "anillo") and then ggplot a bar graph with the xAxis=Number of the Location (NoFrec) and yAxisDistance traveled (Distance). 
This is what I have tried:

```
   plotDist <- function (x) {
     v<-levels(locs.new$anillo)
     as.vector(v)

     for (i in v) {

       print(i)
       da<-subset(locs.new,anillo==i)
       dat<-subset(da, select = c(NoFrec, Distance))
       plot(dat$NoFrec~ dat$Distance)
       print(ggplot(dat, aes(x=NoFrec, y= Distance))) +geom_col() +    ggtitle(as.character(i))

     }
   }
   plotDist(locs.new)
```

If I isolate the code from the for loop and individually create each dataset it works perfectly fine:

```
i<-"XEN010"
da<-subset(locs.new,anillo==i)
dat<-subset(da, select = c(NoFrec, Distance))
plot(dat$NoFrec~ dat$Distance)
print(ggplot(dat, aes(x=NoFrec, y= Distance))) +geom_col() + ggtitle(as.character(i))
```

resulting in:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBiNW.png)
 but the **problem** arises when I insert this code in the for loop. It plots the graphs...but empty of bars and without the Title.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yes! Next time I'll do, I'm new to stack Overflow. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the location of your closing bracket ), your `print` statement **only** outputs the `ggplot()` object, i.e. **excluding** the `geom_col` and the `ggtitle` results. These latter two statements produce your bars and your title. Outside of the function, this does not matter. Inside of the function, it does.

Replace

```
print(ggplot(dat, aes(x=NoFrec, y=Distance))) + geom_col() + ggtitle(as.character(i))
```

by

```
print(ggplot(dat, aes(x=NoFrec, y=Distance)) + geom_col() + ggtitle(as.character(i)))
```

and try again?

NB It would have been helpful if the question would have included some sample data.

Comment: Hope this answers your question, Annamaria. If it does, feel free to mark this answer as 'acceptable'.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was only a matter of closing brackets...I'll upload the data sample set next time!